# How do I access data in a .txt file to assign specific tiles with certain properties in XNA?

Tags: c#, properties, xna, collision, tiles

Okay, at first you may be thinking; "oh great, another question where the guy asking has not researched this before..."

I assure you I have researched this topic thoroughly, with not much luck with my specific problem. My problem is that I have read [this](http://circlessuck.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/xna-tutorial-basic-tile-engine-part-2.html) tutorial which successfully allows me to create a simple .txt file to handle the layout of the level, which then can later be iterated through to read the integer values, and finally draw the corresponding tile textures onto the screen.

In the tutorial linked above, essentially what happens is a Map.cs class is created, which ultimately is responsible for loading in the tile textures:

```
void LoadTileTextures(ContentManager content)
{
      tiles = new List<Texture2D>();
      tiles.Add(content.Load<Texture2D>("Blocks/sky"));           // 0
      tiles.Add(content.Load<Texture2D>("Blocks/grass_block"));   // 1
      tiles.Add(content.Load<Texture2D>("Blocks/dirt_block"));    // 2
      tiles.Add(content.Load<Texture2D>("Blocks/rock_block"));    // 3
}
```

These textures I presume are assigned there numerical value in terms of the order they are loaded in. After this, a method is then created which is responsible for loading, and I guess assigning the tile data:

```
void LoadMapData(string name)
{
      string path = name + ".txt";

      // Width and height of our tile array
      int width = 0;
      int height = File.ReadLines(path).Count();

      StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(path);
      string line = sReader.ReadLine();
      string[] tileNo = line.Split(',');

      width = tileNo.Count();

      // Creating a new instance of the tile map
      tileMap = new int[height, width];
      sReader.Close();

      sReader = new StreamReader(path);

      for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
      {
             line = sReader.ReadLine();
             tileNo = line.Split(',');

             for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
             {
                 tileMap[y, x] = Convert.ToInt32(tileNo[x]);
             }
         }

         sReader.Close();
}
```

http://programming.nullanswer.com/forum/14791

The aforementioned link is a question posted about the same topic, with the same tutorial code. The guy who answered his question was just a little too vague for me personally. I understand what he is getting at, I am just not experienced enough in my own mind to elaborate on what he is suggesting.

Just to re-iterate, my issue is that I am not exactly sure how the data in the .txt file is being assigned to a corresponding tile value. If I knew how this was being done, I would then be able to assign certain values to these tiles within the .txt file. Specifically, I would like to know how to assign a value to each tile in the .txt file such as a boolean, whether it is a solid or not, so I can then go onto creating a Collision() method which manipulates the '.Intersects' function.

Sorry if this has been a loaded question, or come across confusing, but I have reached a wall with this topic that requires a little assistance.

Thank you for taking to time to read this question,

Kind regards, Olly.

Happy coding everyone! ^.^

Comment: You should assign blockIndex `0` to empty space.. Other than `0` are tile indices. This way you always have `width * height` on values. So doing somehing like: `tileMap[y, x] = Convert.ToInt32(tileNo[x]-1);`  But you should check the index bounds before you assign them.

Comment: Thank you for responding so fast, I should have said that I am new to game programming and I am not sure how I would set an empty space. Do you add to the List? tiles.Add(...)? How do you state that it is an empty space? Thanks.

Comment: Just create a map array where the indices are. When the index is `0`, it means you should not draw anything. While drawing you use something like  (pseudo)   `for y -> for x -> if (map[y,x] != 0)   DrawTile(y,x, map[y,x]);`  So, add an if within drawing the map.

Comment: Hmm, okay thank you for this, I certainly accumulated a little more knowledge from your post. How would I go about handling this map array though? Would I create it after the textures are loaded in? Am I being an idiot or something though because how would this map array recognise the texture loading list values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're on the verge of outgrowing this particular tile 
architecture.

In your current code, tiles have only one property: a texture.  Therefore it's sufficient to track your tile definitions by just using a list of textures.  But if you want to add additional properties to your tiles (e.g. a solid flag), you should start by creating a tile definition that can be expanded as you add features:

```
class TileDef
{
    public Texture2D Texture { get; set;}
    public bool IsSolid { get; set; }
}
```

You may eventually want to load tile definitions from a file, but for now you can create them programmatically in the same way that you were loading your textures before:

```
// Replaces function LoadTileTextures
void LoadTileDefinitions(ContentManager content)
{
    tiles = new List<TileDef>();
    tiles.Add(new TileDef() {
        Texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Blocks/sky"),
        IsSolid = false }); // 0
    tiles.Add(new TileDef() {
        Texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Blocks/grass_block"),
        IsSolid = true}); // 1
    tiles.Add(new TileDef() {
        Texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Blocks/dirt_block"),
        IsSolid = true}); // 2
    tiles.Add(new TileDef() {
        Texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Blocks/rock_block"),
        IsSolid = true}); // 3
}
```

The logic for loading your tile map stays the same, because the tile numbers have not changed from before.  But you'll have to change the drawing logic to look for the new Texture property.

Comment: Thank you RogerN, this has given me a great insight into a more methodical, dynamic approach to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add new patterns, you can add it to the tiles first:

```
void LoadTileTextures(ContentManager content)
{
      tiles = new List<Texture2D>();
      tiles.Add(content.Load<Texture2D>("Blocks/sky"));           // 0
      tiles.Add(content.Load<Texture2D>("Blocks/grass_block"));   // 1
      tiles.Add(content.Load<Texture2D>("Blocks/dirt_block"));    // 2
      tiles.Add(content.Load<Texture2D>("Blocks/rock_block"));    // 3
      tiles.Add(content.Load<Texture2D>("Blocks/new_block"));     // 4

}
```

Then you can add 4 as a new value to the txt files where you want to see the new block. 
Ofcourse, you should also create the new_block Texture2D

If you want to avoid the extra texture then you can modify the Draw method:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < tileMap.GetLength(0); y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < tileMap.GetLength(1); x++)
        {
          if(tileMap[y,x] != 4)
            {
            spriteBatch.Draw(
                tiles[tileMap[y, x]],
                new Vector2(x * tileWidth, y * tileHeight),
                Color.White);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although, I would say creating the transparant texture makes the code easier to read and maintein in future.

Comment: Yes thank you for responding, I am aware of how these textures are imported, and added to the list and that new_block would have the numerical value of 4 on the .txt file. I am curious as to how you would add an empty_block to the list, without actually drawing a block that has an alpha value of 0, because clearly this is redundant and uses unnecessary memory. How do I got about accessing these values, so in psuedocode terms: if the integer in the .txt file is equal to 1, set isSolid to true... How do I access these values?

Comment: When the map[y,x] is 0 you should do a lookup.. if it's `!= 0` just use map[y,x]-1  for index.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen van Langen for your useful insights and tips, as well as Nader! Everyone who has answered and helped me out has given me enough information to work upon :D Thanks guys!